# delete folder from trash in Ubuntu

Tags: delete

I delete folder from trash folder by mistake, but I want to retrieve it? 
 I am using Ubuntu 14.10
is there any way to retrieve it again
How can I do that?

Comment: Check out this feed http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=898835. But honestly, if you don't bother too much about those data, just consider them lost.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should stop using the drive or partition.

Next, login from another partition, or from a live disk and have an extra flash drive handy to transfer the lost data to.

Finally, you can use photorec to recover different types of files. To install,run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Then, run the following command to start photorec:

```
photorec
```

For more info on how to use, run:

```
man photorec
```

Note: use the USB to store recovered files to. Do not use the drive you are recovering from to store recovered files.

Other tools to look into (that I have not used):

ext4magic - recover deleted files from ext3 or ext4 partitions

autopsy - graphical interface to SleuthKit

scalpel - A Frugal, High Performance File Carver

sleuthkit - tools for forensics analysis on volume and filesystem data

For a complete list, run the following command:

```
apt-cache search forensics
```

Comment: the problem with photorec is that the name of the file will be lost but the file will be recoverable. Recovered files have random names and you have to go through the files one by one to find the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some applications able to scan file tracks from partitions like [test disk](http://cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Askubuntu and thanks for your answer! However, posting a link as an answer is not accepted here. You should provide the most important parts of the info on that webpage in your answer. Include things in your answer like how to install it and how to use it to recover the trash. If you do these things, comment on your answer with @galgalesh, and I'll upvote your answer.